# Multiple Kafka consumer thread instances running in loop returning empty

Tags: java, apache-kafka

```
public void consumer2(){
    ConsumerThread consumerThread=new ConsumerThread();
    consumerThread.start();
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        ApacheKafkaWebController apacheKafkaWebController = new ApacheKafkaWebController();
        apacheKafkaWebController.producer("test");
    }
    try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        (new ConsumerThread()).start();
    }
public class ConsumerThread extends  Thread {
public void run(){
        ConsumerService consumerService = new ConsumerService();
        consumerService.consumer();

}
public ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> consumer(){
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    //props.put("group.id", "test");
    props.put("group.id", String.valueOf(Instant.now().getEpochSecond()));
    props.put("auto.offset.reset","earliest");
    props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
    //props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
    props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer");
    KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);
    consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList("topiccc"));
    ConsumerRecords<String, byte[]> records = consumer.poll(100);
    consumer.seekToBeginning(consumer.assignment());
   /* List<byte[]> videoContents = new ArrayList<byte[]>();
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, byte[]> record : records) {
        System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s\n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
        videoContents.add(record.value());
    }*/
    System.out.println("ISSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS EMPTYYYYYYYYYY:"+String.valueOf(records.isEmpty()));
    System.out.println("RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRCOUNT:"+records.count());
    return records;

}
@GetMapping(value = "/producer")
public String producer(@RequestParam("message") String message) {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    // list of host:port pairs used for establishing the initial connections to the Kakfa cluster
    props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer");
    Producer<String, byte[]> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    Path path = Paths.get("C:/Programming Files/video-2012-07-05-02-29-27.mp4");
    ProducerRecord<String, byte[]> record = null;
    try {
        //byte[] arr= (Arrays.copyOf(Files.readAllBytes(path),2000000));
        record = new ProducerRecord<>("topiccc", "keyyyyy"
                , Files.readAllBytes(path));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    producer.send(record);
    producer.close();
    //kafkaSender.send(record);

    return "Message sent to the Kafka Topic java_in_use_topic Successfully";
}
```

I have 10 consumer threads running in a loop which call Kafka consumer after producer has been called many times to insert records but the consumers return empty.

I have set group id to a different value every time it is called so that the record stays in Kafka and consumers are able to download it. I have also called consumer many times via browser and tested the group id thing worked.

Comment: consumer should be running before the producer send the messages to kafka or you should set the consumer config to fetch from the earlier offset

Comment: can you share the code snippet

Comment: @andani I shared the code